# How to fix this mutating error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring

I'm getting this error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with replaceCharactersInRange:withString:'`

But I can't figure out what immutable object I'm mutating.

```
        NSRange subRange = [self.label.text rangeOfString: @"="];
        int numA = 5;
        int numB = 3;

        NSMutableString *mixed = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i %i", numA, numB];

        NSMutableString *string = [NSString stringWithString: self.label.text];

        subRange = [string rangeOfString: @"="];

        if (subRange.location != NSNotFound)
            [string replaceCharactersInRange:subRange withString:mixed];
```

Comment: Your string variable isn't mutable and you ate attempting to mutate it.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541212/attempt-to-mutate-immutable-object-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267956/error-for-attempting-mutating-immutable-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `NSMutableString` creation calls aren't balanced properly. You're promising the compiler that you're creating a `NSMutableString` but you ask an `NSString` to create an instance.

For example:

`NSMutableString *mixed = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i %i", numA, numB];`

needs to be:

`NSMutableString *mixed = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%i %i", numA, numB];`

Answer (score 1):

Your `NSMutableString`s are actually instances of `NSString`. This is runtime detail, though there should at least be a warning for those lines. Change to:

```
NSMutableString *string = [self.label.text mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `NSMutableString` like this:

```
[NSMutableString stringWithString: self.label.text];
```